# Sort / order items from Firebase database in React native listView

Tags: listview, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, datasource

I have a list of items extracted from Firebase database and I need to sort/ order them by the alphabetic order in my react native app. So here is the code I'm using :

```
listenForItems(itemsRef) {
        itemsRef.on('value', (snap) => {

            let items = [];
            snap.forEach((child) => {
                items.push({
                    name: child.val().name,
                    _key     : child.key
                });
            });

            this.setState({
                dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(items)
            });

        }); 
    }


render() {
        return (
                <ListView
                    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this.props)}
                    enableEmptySections={true}/>
        );
    }
```

I found this http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-query but I really didn't know how to use the sort method of the datasource. Any help? I'm also open for any other solution to sort items in react native listview.

Answer (score 1):

Just sort the list using `Array.prototype.sort` before you apply it into your dataset. I've removed the RN code for now as it breaks the snippet.

```js
let items = [{
  name: 'Z'
}, {
  name: 'A'
}, {
  name: 'Y'
}];

let sorted = items.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.name < b.name) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.name > b.name) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: thank you .. but i don't think it's applicable in my case : i have a large amount of data that i don't  know before getting them from the Firebase database ... Actually items in my case is being dynamically charged from the database while using the app